# Distributed Marketing Business Unit Issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, distributed-marketing

I am trying to configure distributed marketing and in the very first step I am running up against this error when adding a business unit: Error: You do not have the required permissions to configure a business unit.

I have the the DM permission sets and have a standard user in Sales Cloud with Enterprise Marketing Cloud. I also have the Marketing Cloud connected app permission set.

The one thing that I believe could be the cause is that the Distributed Marketing app is running from Sandbox, while Marketing Cloud is connected to the live org. Would that be the reason why I can't move forward?

Comment: Are you using multi org or single org MCC?

Comment: To confirm you have assigned the DMadmin permission set: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_dm_assign_permissions.htm&type=0

Comment: @EazyE Using single org and just confirmed that I do have both DMadmin sets.

Comment: One additional aspect that might part of the issue is that I am not integrated with the account in SFMC. I am a sandbox user only and not production. Could the be the possible answer?